# Symfony Serializer issue - NotNormalizableValueException

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle

I have an issue when I'm using the serializer with FOSRestBundle in Symfony 4.1

I have the following error message :

> Could not normalize object of type App\Entity\Youp, no supporting normalizer found.
>   Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException

I don't understand why I have this issue, Symfony's Serializer should have an serializer object or I miss something ?

See bellow my controller and my entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\YoupRepository")
 */
class Youp
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

use App\Entity\Youp;

class BidonController extends FOSRestController {

  /**
   * @Rest\View()
   * @Rest\Get("/youps")
   */
  public function getPharmacies() {
    $youps = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Youp::class)->findAll();
    return $youps; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your object's properties are `private` so the serializer doesn't know how to normalize or get any data from your object. You can either set the properties to `public` or enable the `ObjectNormalizer` (which uses the PropertyAccess Component to access the private/protected properties) and/or `GetSetMethodNormalizer` (which reads the content of the class by calling the "getters") using the following service-definition in your configuration:

```
services:
  # [..]
  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer
    public: false
    tags:
      - { name: 'serializer.normalizer' }

  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
    public: false
    tags:
      - { name: 'serializer.normalizer' }
```

Clear your cache afterwards. More information about the normalizers already included in the serializer component can be found in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers)

Comment: Yes it was that ! Thank a lot. I have misunderstood the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me, but we need to install symfony/property-access before using it. I came across a related exception.